# FCM wont stack similar messages?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to stack similar messages instead of sending separate notification for every same message.

Below is my code

```
 const payload = {
      notification: {
        title: `added new report`,
        body: change.after.data().report_title,
        tag: "ReportLog",
      },
      data: {
        click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
        sound: "default",
        status: "done",
      },
    };

    const options = {
      priority: "high",
      collapseKey: "ReportLog",
    };

await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload, options);
```

SO suppose i send the same message again and again , instead of stacking the messages, the old notification get replace by new

Answer (score 1):

On the server side you can "remember" the last notify and don't send another. (Bad idea)

On the client you can do the same. (Also bad idea)
But the thing is, that the "remember" logic won't work if the app is the background, because the notify will be handled by the system and not by your logic in the app.